# No module named layers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.0.0 and I want to access the tensorflow.layers module. The module seems to exist:

```
In [12]: dir(tensorflow.layers)
Out[12]: 
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_allowed_symbols',
 'average_pooling1d',
 'average_pooling2d',
 'average_pooling3d',
 'batch_normalization',
 'conv1d',
 'conv2d',
 'conv2d_transpose',
 'conv3d',
 'dense',
 'dropout',
 'max_pooling1d',
 'max_pooling2d',
 'max_pooling3d',
 'separable_conv2d']
```

But when I try to import e.g. the dense function:

```
In [13]: from tensorflow.layers import dense
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e5b2c910300d> in <module>()
----> 1 from tensorflow.layers import dense

ImportError: No module named layers
```

Why can python not access the module?

Comment: `from tensorflow.python.layers.core import dense` seems to work. Or just `from tensorflow import layers`, then call `layers.dense`.

Comment: This works for me: from tensorflow import layers...and then calling the functions I need. However, I don't understand why a direct import fails ?!

Comment: why do you need to import the functions specifically? "import tensorflow as tf" and "x = tf.layers.dense(...)" works fine and is morereadable

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your installation or workspace:

- Make sure you don’t have a directory called ‘tensorflow” in your Python Path.
- Install again the official tensorflow distro `pip install —upgrade —ignore-installed tensorflow)`
- Make sure you are using the right tensorflow version `print(tensorflow.__version__)`

Comment: Still doesn't work for me...even with different types of installations. With v1.2.1 installed using pip (with anaconda 2), didn't work. Same thing but with native python2.7. I even compiled tensorflow from sources (v1.3): all other imports work but not tf.layers. I checked the existence of layers.py in the tensorflow install directory. I don't understand why it doesn't work